# Finding distance between 2 geospatial location in aws neptune with opencypher query language

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-neptune, opencypher

I am working with amazon neptune and using openCypher query language and doing some stuff using notebook. I have latitude and longitude of 2 points and I want to calculate the distance between these 2 points. For the purpose I am using Haversine formula. However to do this it required trigonometric functions like sin and cos and seems that those are not supported yet with neptune and openCypher. I am stuck here as I will be heavily doing operations on location. Any alternate solution without using sin cos ?

Answer (score 1):

Until the trigonometric functions are added to the openCypher support provided by Amazon Neptune (which hopefully will appear fairly soon), you could do this particular calculation using Gremlin. An example query is [available here](https://kelvinlawrence.net/book/PracticalGremlin.html#GreatCircle). In summary, it looks like this (assuming both the start and stop vertices have properties called `lat` and `lon` providing the coordinates in decimal form):

```java
g.withSideEffect("rdeg", 0.017453293).
  withSideEffect("gcmiles",3956).
  V().has('code',start).as('src').
  V().has('code',stop).as('dst').
  select('src','dst').
    by(project('lat','lon').
         by('lat').
         by('lon')).
  as('grp').
  project('ladiff','lgdiff','lat1','lon1','lat2','lon2').
    by(project('la1','la2').
         by(select('grp').select('src').select('lat')).
         by(select('grp').select('dst').select('lat')).
       math('(la2 - la1) * rdeg')).
    by(project('lg1','lg2').
         by(select('grp').select('src').select('lon')).
         by(select('grp').select('dst').select('lon')).
       math('(lg2 - lg1) * rdeg')).
    by(select('grp').select('src').select('lat')).
    by(select('grp').select('src').select('lon')).
    by(select('grp').select('dst').select('lat')).
    by(select('grp').select('dst').select('lon')).
  math('(sin(ladiff/2))^2 + cos(lat1*rdeg) * cos(lat2*rdeg) * (sin(lgdiff/2))^2').
  math('gcmiles * (2 * asin(sqrt(_)))')
```

Comment: Thanks @Kelvin , Looks like only solution I have right now is to switch to gremlin and do the stuff.

Comment: Hopefully the openCypher support will be forthcoming. I'll update this answer at the appropriate time.